# Add a string to the url using .htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess

I need help with redirecting in my .htaccess file. I would like to add a string to whatever is at the end of the url. For example:

When someone goes to this url:

`www.mysite.com/example`

I would like to rewrite the url to say this:

`www.mysite.com/result.html?search=example`

So I just need to add the string `result.html?search=` before whatever is at the end of the URL.

The word example is just a placeholder, I need any word that is put back there to work.

Comment: Sorry, but it is unclear what you actually ask. Please be precise in your question: which of the two variants is the _external_ URL actually requested by clients (browsers) and what _internal_ resource should it be rewritten to? Your example reads a bit as if you are looking for a redirection, not a rewriting.

Comment: the url that is requested by the client is `www.mysite.com/example` and the internal resource is should be rewritten to is `www.mysite.com/result.html?search=example`

Comment: example is folder or file?

Comment: @MohammedElhag example is a query string that will be grabbed and put into a function, so i guess neither file or folder

Answer (score 1):

This should be helpful.

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^page/([^/]+)/? result.html?search=$1
```

Comment: To me the question actually reads different, which is why I preferred to ask before posting any answer...

Comment: @arkascha What you are saying also makes sense, question can be looked from different perspectives, but I think this is what he is trying to achieve here. Let's seek some more clarification.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your additional comment the question I assume this is what you are actually looking for:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?(.+)/?$ /result.html?search=$1 [END]
```

If you experience a http status 500 with that rule ("internal server error"), then chances are that you operate a very old version of the apache http server. Try using the `[L]` flag then instead of the `[END]` flag. You will find a corresponding hint in your http servers error log file in that case too.

The above rule will work likewise in the http servers host configuration and in a dynamic configuration file (`.htaccess` style file). Obviously the rewriting module must be loaded and activated in the http server for that. If you decide to use a dynamic configuration file then you also need to make sure that such files are actually considered by the http server. Read about the `AllowOverride` directive in the documentation for that.

And a general hint: you should always prefer to place such rules inside the http servers (virtual) host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (`.htaccess` style files). Those files are notoriously error prone, hard to debug and they really slow down the server. They are only supported as a last option for situations where you do not have control over the host configuration (read: really cheap hosting service providers) or if you have an application that relies on writing its own rewrite rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

Comment: Brilliant :) Despite just assumption, your answer has much depth.

Comment: thanks for your answer but I am getting a 500 error with both `[L]` and `[END]` I learned alot from your answer though so thanks!

Comment: @cup_of Most likely reason would be that the rewriting module is _not_ loaded based on your comment... As already mentioned: you should take a look into your http servers error log file. That is where you can read more detailed, internal information about the issue the server ran into.

Comment: I am using a local server for now (MAMP), I need to do some research to find that error log file

Comment: In the apache http server you will find the `ErrorLog` directive, that is what you are looking for: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#errorlog